# как сделать запись if короче

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

```
$(el).bind 'touchmove mousemove touchstart mousedown', (e) ->
    if e.type is 'touchstart' or e.type is 'mousedown'
        start = true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```
$(el).bind 'touchmove mousemove touchstart mousedown', (e) ->
    if e.type in ['touchstart', 'mousedown'] 
        start = true
```

Еще здесь можно использовать `switch`:

```
$(el).bind 'touchmove mousemove touchstart mousedown', (e) ->
    switch e.type
        when 'touchstart', 'mousedown'
            start = true
        else
            //whatever
```

Не очень уверен насчёт CoffeeScript синтаксиса, но идея должна быть понятна